# How to send data from iPhone to Watch with SwiftUI

Tags: swift, iphone, swiftui, watchos

i have found many solutions on how to send data from an iPhone to an connected Apple Watch with WatchConnectivity, but only with Storyboards or WatchKit.

I haven't found a solution on how to send data if I use SwiftUI on the iPhone and on the Watch.

Does anyone know how to implement this with SwiftUI?

Comment: SwiftUI is a UI framework, it has nothing to do with sending data between different devices. You need to use WatchKit to handle that, so the existing answers you found should still apply.

Comment: So it does not work with SwiftUI in watchOS?

Comment: Again, this has nothing to do with SwiftUI. SwiftUI is a UI framework, you cannot use it without WatchKit on watchOS, since WatchKit needs to handle the non-UI parts of your app. You cannot make network requests with SwiftUI either, why do you expect to be able to handle communication between different devices with SwiftUI?